# Laravel 5.2 - running migrations with --env is not pointing to correct env file

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

So we have a SaaS implementation of laravel that uses different .env files per client like so: .env.. It works great. However, when I try to run artisan commands like `php artisan migrate --env=<client_id>` it still uses the base .env file. If i try to rename the .env to .env.back and run it only picks up the defaults.

Please help!

**Edit**: I have also used `php artisan --env=<client_id> migrate` to no avail. Its like the command doesn't take env into account.

After further review I realized that the Migrate Command does not take advantage of the --env option. So I manually set the .env file and got it to pick up the .env.iwlu60 file. However, it still was looking at the .env database. Im stumped again.

**Edit 2**: I have "solved" this by creating wrapper commands that take advantage of the --env flag. My question still stands though. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug or maybe even intended?

Comment: Can you write your .env file name? Is it .env.<client_id> ? You can try php artisan --env=<client_id> migrate

Comment: sure.... the file name is .env.iwlu60 and i have run `php artisan --env=iwlu60 migrate` as well as `php artisan migrate --env=iwlu60`....nothing

Comment: This may be a little off topic but have you made sure that you are not getting cached versions of your .env file? `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I just double checked and yes it's cleared and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was a bug. --env was included in the base commands but never truly implemented. I have not looked since 5.2 to see if they have fixed this.

Answer (score -2):

The artisan `--env` option refers to the `APP_ENV` variable defined in the `.env` file. It has nothing to do with the filename of the `.env` file.

Comment: Look in the laravel docs and you will see that if you set APP_ENV it will grab a .env.<APP_ENV> file instead of the base .env file....

Comment: Uh, no. How do you imagine that working? You set the variable to define which file to load in the file itself? This was  somewhat true with Laravel 4,  if you set a super global to define the environment.